# How to set the hint properly in a text Box means EditText in android

Tags: android

I am using **EditText** and providing some Hint there. I am putting it like this:

```
android:hint="@string/user_name_hint"
android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
android:gravity="left"
```

But here hint is coming in the left side. But i want the hint is in the middle of the box and when i am clicking the text should start from the left.

How it is possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `EditText`

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:hint="user_name_hint"
    android:textColorHint="#fffff"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"/>
```

Then you need to add `addTextChangedListener` to solve your problem.

```
 final EditText hintText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            hintText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                        int count) {
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (s.length() == 0) {
                        hintText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    } else {
                        hintText.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: But it still coming in the left side only, by using addTextChangeListener.

Comment: Actually when i am setting the gravity as left then only hint is showing. But other than that, hint is not showing. I am not getting whats happened there..

Comment: Changed the answer..Take a look.

Comment: did you added it `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`..It will working fine on 2.2 here.

Comment: yes..i added..but it is only showing the cursor in the center of the text box.

Comment: <EditText 
      android:id="@+id/Login_TxtBox"
      android:layout_width="160px"
      android:layout_height="20px"
      android:layout_marginLeft="150px"
         android:layout_marginTop="45px"
         android:textSize="10px"
         android:background="#8b8989"
         android:singleLine="true"
         android:hint="@string/user_name_hint"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
     >

Comment: Actually i am doing for Android Tablet, simulator galaxy tab

Comment: it is not coming. if i remove that then text box layout will change. I take that because i want the text box in the middle of the screen.

Comment: why its happening, i dont know. But thanks for your help and reply. I send you frnd request in FB. :0..

Answer (score 0):

set Gravity to center.. android:gravity="center_horizontal"

Comment: If i put android:gravity="center_horizontal" then when i am start entering the text in the text box it is starting from middle.

Comment: then let me give yo silly idea... not a good one but still u go u r string user_name_hint and give some blank space initially... only way to go i guess.. not sure..:)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do it in a "straight forward way". Probably some workaround - either suggested by nagesh or by placing a button on top of the edit text and switching to  edit text when it gets clicked or focused